# Do comments work on the Blog site?

Tags: bug, status-completed, blog

I'm unable to post a comment to the blog site.  I get an "Invalid Referrer" error where the captcha should be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to a configuration issue a few days ago, I made a change to fix this issue on the gaming blog.  I didn't realize that fixing the gaming blog broke things elsewhere.  Sorry about that folks - things should be good to go now.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I was able to post a comment here

http://security.blogoverflow.com/2011/08/09/apple-bringing-secure-email-to-the-masses-with-ios-5/#comment-31

in Google Chrome Incognito mode.. so it's working for me.